# how to diagnose why my python kernel died?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I've already seen and read the many threads that exist on this matter, usually there are linked to extremely specific bugs, lib conflicts or memory shortage. Here I'm more looking for a general answer that will guide me to find the source of my kernel death.

### question

Can someone explain me what can lead to kernel death and what are the steps I could follow to find the source and debug it ?

### small context

I'm doing automatic change detection on country-sized time series using the [bfast](https://github.com/diku-dk/bfast). running it my test time series give me very interesting results:

[image]

The problem is raised when I try to run other time series. The process starts and after several hours without any warning or error, my kernel died.